# Does Telerik Reporting support Business Object Datasources?

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I have a requirement to use business objects to call strongly typed table adapters in a three tier model.  I also have a requirement to use Telerik reporting, which I didn't see any examples of online.  I just see simple examples of creating a simple select to Northwind and connecting the report directly to that.  I am using 2008 Q3 of Telerik reporting and my designer doesn't even look the same as the videos I've seen.  I have two business objects: boReportHeader and boReportLines and they each have 4 methods that will be passed parameters from the Ui and need to fill the report header and detail section.  I spent some time trying to use these from Telerik reporting from both the designer and code-behind and I haven't been successful.  I was assuming this would be as straight forward as the RadGrid, but it doesn't appear to be.  Anyone have experience with using multiple business object data sources with parameters as a datasource for Telerik Reporting?  The main requirement for this project is to generate a PDF file that will be stored in the database as a BLOB file.  If this is not possible with Telerik Reporting, does anyone have another tool to suggest other than Telerik Reporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You can. See the code below.

```
namespace TelerikReporting {
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.Reporting;
using Telerik.Reporting.Drawing;

public partial class Rep2 : Telerik.Reporting.Report {

    public static int GetTotal(int male, int female) {
        return (male + female);
    }
    public Rep2() {

        InitializeComponent();

        // I am initializing my DataClass.
        MyData d = new MyData();

        // Adding the DataSource.
        this.DataSource = d.GetCityMFCount();

    }
}
}
```

Finally, You call this report in the report Viewer.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Rep2 rep = new Rep2();
        ReportViewer1.Report = rep;


    }
```

Hope this Helps.

Liby George